# Nesting query results in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that produces a result that looks like the following:

| session_id | country | vendor_id | page_name | qty_visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a | abc | home | 1 |
| 123 | a | abc | shop | 4 |
| 456 | b | abc | home | 78 |
| 456 | b | xyz | home | 9 |
| 456 | b | xyz | cart | 6 |

I want to nest this table so that `page_name` and `qty_vistis` are arrays inside a `struct` called `page_visits`. Basically, my end result should be a table with three rows (identified by `session_id`, `country`, and `vendor_id`), with a fourth column called `page_visits` which itself is a struct with two columns, each of which is an array. One of said columns has a list of all the pages visited, the other one has the number of times it was visited. Like so

| session_id | country | vendor_id | page_visits.page_name | page_visits.qty_visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a | abc | home | 1 |
|  |  |  | shop | 4 |
| 456 | b | abc | home | 78 |
| 456 | b | xyz | home | 9 |
|  |  |  | cart | 6 |

As a check, the result of `select count(*) from final_table` should be 3, as opposed to 5 (which is what one would get without the nesting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg):

```
select
  session_id,
  country,
  vendor_id,
  array_agg(struct(page_name, qty_visits)) as page_visits
from mytable
group by session_id, country, vendor_id
```

Comment: I was missing the `GROUP BY` in my tries!! You are a genius! thanks a lot!! I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me!!